# Unable to retrieve group that has all user

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I am trying to retrieve all groups for a member, [Link](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list). I have noticed that if a group that has all the users, it will not be retrieved. 
Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same scenario in [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list) and retrieved the group that has all the users. Just added the domain and userKey parameters and i can see the group in the list.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not work for me. You can refer here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bAvCX00wn3E9oIckJf77q-29DbY1lJvQfZupZAoP9C0/edit?usp=sharing